# Mapping a Java native function to an array of char results in exception

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

So I was trying this:

```
user=> (Integer/toBinaryString ^int (.charValue \c))
"1100011"
user=>
```

And I thought... Well, that looks promising, so let's try this now:

```
user=> (map #(Integer/toBinaryString ^int (.charValue %)) "some")

ClassCastException java.lang.Character cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  user/eval1209/fn--1210 (form-init3852254868488042860.clj:1)
user=> ; Tried this as well. But without luck:
user=> (map #(Integer/toBinaryString ^int (.charValue %)) (.toCharArray "some"))

ClassCastException java.lang.Character cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  user/eval1249/fn--1250 (form-init3852254868488042860.clj:1)
user=>
```

oops! WTF is going on?

I have the thing working after introducing a hack:

```
user=> (map #(Integer/toBinaryString ^int (.charValue (Character/valueOf %))) "some")
("1110011" "1101111" "1101101" "1100101")
user=> ; Or alternatively:
user=> (map (fn [^Character c] (Integer/toBinaryString ^int (.charValue c))) "some")
("1110011" "1101111" "1101101" "1100101")
user=> ; Or:
user=> (map #(Integer/toBinaryString ^int (.charValue ^Character %)) "some")
("1110011" "1101111" "1101101" "1100101")
user=>
```

So, does anyone know why this just won't work without calling `Character/valueOf` or explicitly casting?

Comment: trying your very first statement in http://web.clojurerepl.com/ gives the same ClassCastException as your map version. ^int is not a cast. your type hint isn't converting to int. I'm not sure why you're getting a result for this at all on your first statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type hints aren't meant to change a program's semantics. The supposed way to convert a character to a number in Clojure is the `int` function.

Example:

```
user=> (map #(-> % int Integer/toBinaryString) "some")
("1110011" "1101111" "1101101" "1100101")
```

So to be clear, in Clojure, `char`s are supposed to always be autoboxed into `Character`s which aren't numbers. The weird part in your code is therefore not when treating `char`s as numbers doesn't work, but when it does, because in those cases the type hints change the semantics of your code which they aren't supposed to.

Comment: Exactly my question. Why is it I have to cast a Character to a Character in order for it to work as I posted it? (Also, I like your solution a lot better. Thanks :)

Comment: @dsm: Like I said, type hints are *not* casts, they aren't supposed to change behaviour but rather exclusively support compiler optimizations. In this case though, you were sometimes able to trigger what is basically implementation-dependant behaviour, i.e. to use the `toBinaryString` method on the result of `.charValue`, even though in Clojure the result of `.charValue` isn't supposed to be a number.

Comment: The problem is not there. I knew I had to coerce it in that place as `toBinaryString` is a `java.lang.Number` static method, hence the cast/type-hint. The exception arises when the anonymous function takes a `Character` as an argument to `.charValue`. This is what I am finding really hard to get my head around. Looks like a bug, TBH.

Comment: Continued: But it only happens when the call is nested, hence the slightly convoluted example. If you try plain old `(map #(.charValue %) "some")` you get the expected result.

Comment: Either that or I'm misreading the exception, which is a real possibility as it says cannot cast from Character to Number...

Comment: @dsm: The problem is that `Character` isn't a number, but `char` is. `char` gets autoboxed to `Character` by Clojure (which is a somewhat arbitrary decision: often `char`s are meant to represent characters and should become `Character`s, but sometimes they're meant to represent integers and should become `Long`s). Your type hints allowed you to sometimes "trick" Clojure and use `char`s as numbers, even though the autoboxing semantics of Clojure mean that this shouldn't be possible.